# Docker - load base image from artifactory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker, and any help would be much appreciated

**Here is setup**

- Artifactory URL: https://www.myarti.com/directory/library/test/1.0.0
- In Explorer, URL without http won't work (myarti.com/directory/library/test/1.0.0)
- Images are stored under the above folder.
- The user needs 'Read Access' in order to read/see the images

**What I am trying to do**

Load images from the artifactory, and then use as Base Image.

**Efforts**

In DockerFiles, I undertand 'From' keyword is necessary to load base image. I tried 3 different ways, but not working.

1. From https://www.myarti.com/directory/library/test:1.0.0

   `Service 'builder-el6' failed to build: Error parsing reference: "https://www.myarti.com/directory/library/test:1.0.0" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format`
2. From www.myarti.com/directory/library/test:1.0.0

   `Service 'builder-el6' failed to build: Error: Status 400 trying to pull repository myarti.com/directory/library/test/1.0.0: "{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : 400,\n    \"message\" : \"Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'www'\"\n  } ]\n}"`
3. From myarti.com/directory/library/test:1.0.0

   `Service 'builder-el6' failed to build: Get https://myarti.com/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9999: i/o timeout / or Service Unavailable`

If this issue is due to 'access', how can I provide? (ex. username=test / pwd=password). I found 'Login' command, but as far as I know 'From' commnad should be the first line of DockerFile. Should be part of docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change the default docker registry, on the machine you're trying to build the image on, to Artifactory.

[Here's the documentation on how to change the registry.](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/)

Then you should modify your `Dockerfile` to not use any host informations in it. So it's probably going to be this:

```
FROM library/test:1.0.0
```

Finally you should learn the basics first. Here's a very good guided starting point. https://training.play-with-docker.com